# How to properly add items in the beginning of horizontal UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm trying to achieve next behavior:

1. I add few items in the beginning of `UICollectionView`
2. Items are added with proper animation, but I keep content offset on current center cell (it will be first cell before adding new items).

How I'm doing it now:

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
    contentOffset.x += kMyCollectionViewCellWidth * firstIndex;
    ((MyCollectionViewLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout).proposedContentOffset = contentOffset;
    [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexesToAdd];
  } completion:nil];
```

And in `MyCollectionViewLayout.m`:

```
- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset {
  if (self.proposedContentOffset.x != NSNotFound) {
    proposedContentOffset = self.proposedContentOffset;
    CGPoint zeroPoint = CGPointZero;
    zeroPoint.x = NSNotFound;
    self.proposedContentOffset = zeroPoint;
  }
  return proposedContentOffset;
}
```

Though, on slow devices I can see weird animation of adding this cells. New cells appears above old ones and moves left, when I want them appear in the left immediately or at least under old cells.